# Login handling in Vue - Is checking the status code sufficient?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication

In a Vue app I have a login. With email and password I send a POST request against the node express backend. If email and password don't match I send back a 409 HTTP status code with a message: "No access!  In my POST fetch block I intercept the status code and check if I didn't get a 200 status. If this is the case, I send an error message. If I have a 200 status code I put the JWT token into a cookie. This works. But to be honest, I find the check for the status code too low.

What approaches are there to check the login response. Are there other approaches? Thanks a lot!

```js
    async submit() {
      try {
        const d = await fetch(config.apiUri + "sign-in", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'omit',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.data),
        });
        const j = await d.json();

        if (d.status !== 200) {
          this.errorMsg = j.message
          console.log(this.errorMsg)
          return;
        }
        
        accessHelper.setToken(j.token, this.mys);
        accessHelper.setAuth = true;
        this.$router.push("/");          
      } catch(err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong", err)
      }

    }
```

Comment: For a failed login you may want to respond with a 401 (Unauthorized) or 403 (Forbidden).  As for checking something other than the status code, that depends on what errors can be thrown by your server. If you only return a 200 when successful then there really isn't a reason to check anything else. If you think you will return a 200 for some reason when the login failed, then you will have to check something in addition to the status code. In the end, it comes down to how you decide to architecture the application.

Comment: Thank you @DanielBlack for your good comment! I think you are right. In addition to the status code, I have to include something in the response that confirms an error. Since I want to display an error message from the server in the frontend, I have to do it that way. Many thanks and greetings to Canada :-)!

Answer (score 0):

For login use cases most "magic" happens on the server. That includes

- hashing and salting the password when it's stored and updated,
- hashing and checking the received password during logins
- You'd want to lock accounts after a certain number of failed logins
- and lock IPs after a certain number of failed logins.

After a successful login you're server sends some kind of authentication information (in your case a JWT), which allows the frontend to access secured endpoints. The frontend can't really know more than the fact that the username / password combination was not correct. Therefore, it's fine to only check for the status code.

[This OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://owasp.deteact.com/cheat/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html) contains some useful information in regards to Authentication.

If you feel uncomfortable with handling logins you could think about using OAUTH with e.g. [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps) and/or authentication services like [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)